# Battery always says 0%

Tags: battery

I'm using a fresh install of Loki 64bit on an Asus UX32VD. The battery always shows 0% and I get a "find your charger now!" message when I disconnect the laptop from the charger. WHen I click the battery icon, where it should indicate the time left, it keeps saying "calculating".Strange thing is that I can go on working like this for some time. 
So, I think the battery is somehow not completely recognized. Is that possible?
I also had this issue on previous elementary instals.
 I have plucked out my charger from laptop it shutdown .

Comment: Does this also happen when you boot a different OS? if so, it could be that your battery is not connecting right.